# Prove that it's a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following definition of $V_a$:

$$V_a := \{(x, y, z)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3 : y = 3x - az\}, \quad \text{for $a \in \mathbb{R}$}.$$

My first problem: I don't understand this definition. Which role does $a$ play in this formula? How do the vectors look like? Why there's only $y$ given, what about $x$ and $z$?

Second problem (which is no wonder taking into account the first one): How can I find a basis of $V_a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$

And one more: How can I prove that $V_a$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Please, help me to understand and to solve these problems.

Comment: The index $a$ simply identifies which subspace we’re talking about. For instance, $$V_\pi=\{(x,y,z)^t\in\Bbb R^3:y=3x-\pi z\}\;.$$ There’s one of these subspaces for each real number $a$.

Comment: To prove $V_a$ to be a subspace is very easy since obviously it is the kernel of the linear map $(x,y,z)\mapsto 3x-y-az$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ you take, you get a different $V_a$. For example,

$$V_0 = \{ (x,y,z)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}, \ y = 3x \} = \{ (x,3x,z)^T \colon x,z \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$

For a general $a$, you have

$$V_a = \{ (x,y,z)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}, \ y = 3x-az \} = \{ (x,3x-az,z)^T \colon x,z \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$

Note that

$$(x,3x-az,z)^T = x(1,3,0)^T + z(0,-a,1)^T$$

for all $x,z \in \mathbb{R}$. So, the set $\{(1,3,0)^T, (0,-a,1)^T\}$ spans $V_a$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$. To prove that it's basis, you need to show that these two vectors are linearly independent.

I'll let you take over now. Feel free to ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I have one question concerning subspace-proof:
I've proven that a sum of two vectors is in the same space + the origin is also included. 

Now I have to prove that a product with a scalar is also in the same space. Does the following reasoning make sense:

$k(x_1, x_2, x_3)^t = k(x_1, 3x_1 - ax_3, x_3) = (kx_1, 3kx_1 - akx_3, kx_3)$ => so the second condition is hold.

Comment: Yes, apart from the typo (you've lost the transpose). :-)

Comment: So what you've done is split up the initial vector into two vector combinations which equal the initial vector and see that they aren't dependent, that the null vector exists and that it satisfies closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @KarlMorrison Kinda, but some things are obvious. Since I have used the form $xv_1 + zv_2$, it is obvious that it contains the zero vector (for $x = y = 0$)and the closure is pretty much clear from the construction. Btw, linear independence of two vectors follows from the zeros in the different positions, but a more formal proof is probably required if this is a part of an exam. Feel free to ask further if I've left something unclear. It's an old answer, after all. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is just some fixed constant. You want to show that $V_a$ is a subspace for all $a$.

Second, it's not that $y$ is given, none of $x,y,z$ is "given". You are told that $V_a$ is the set of all $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $y=3x-az=0$, i.e. all points $(x,y,z)$ that lie on the plane given by $3x-y-az=0$. Namely $V_a$ **is** the plane described by $3x-y-az=0$.

Now what do you know about planes? They are subspaces iff they contain the origin. It is easy to see that $30-0-a0=0$ so indeed $V_a$ is a subspace.

Finally, to find a basis for $V_a$ all you need is any two nonparallel vectors in the plane. Try to find two such vectors by looking for two of the form $(0,1,z_1)$ and $(1,0,z_2)$ which lie on the plane. Any two nonparallel vectors will work, but these seem the obvious choices. (If $a=0$ be careful though, maybe other choices would be best.)